# scss : the ampersand css operator is not working for my html page

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
a {
  &:visited {
    color: cyan;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: orangered;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS operator</h1>
<dl>
  <dt><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap CSS Home page</a></dt>
  <dd>BOOTSTRAP CSS</dd>
  <dt><a href= "https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto">Sorting</a></dt>
  <dd>Python Sorting</dd>
</dl>
```

Issue regarding the & CSS operator and pseudo selector:

(1) If I am hovering over the a href link for say BOOTSTRAP CSS, it is not changing color to orangered as per
&:hover {color: orangered;}

(2) The link color is not changing to cyan after I visit the ahref link(click) as per:   &:visited {color: cyan;}

Comment: You cannot run scss in browser you need to compile it to standard css

Comment: how to do that? if possible can you send some documentation links

Comment: You can read about scss and sass [here](https://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other CSS preprocessors like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules#nesting) (for e.g.), CSS doesn't support nesting styles.

The following is what you need for pure CSS:

```css
a:visited {
  color: cyan;
}

a:hover {
  color: orangered;
}
```

Comment: that  would work but my question is to use the & css operator

Comment: & is not (at the moment) a CSS operator.